# How can I do a triangle shape in Blender?

Tags: modeling, objects

I want to do the shape below in Blender. I am a developer and I have no idea about Blender. I will be grateful if you can tell me the steps simply.

The shape I am trying to do:

[image]

The shape I have done:

[image]

I have tried to combine 4 squares to obtain it.

How can I trim the upper parts?

Comment: You should build that from 1 single mesh or use mirror modifier to get result to shape like that

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a plane, inset with <kbd>i</kbd>:

[image]

Delete the face with <kbd>X</kbd>, rotate 90° on X, rotate 45° on Y:

[image]

Delete the bottom part, select the bottom edges and extrude down:

[image]

Extrude on Y with <kbd>E</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: I think from all the answers posted here yours and mine are the only ones that have a right angle on the top corner, as it looks to be in the original... and yours is the easiest way to build this. Voted up.

Comment: thanks, yes it looks like there are a lot of ways to do it  ^^

Answer (score 13):

2D Curves are very useful for creating mitered corners in a profile of even thickness. You can construct this arch from just 3 points, and it remains adjustable, by moving them around.

Working in the XY plane, with Transform Pivot set to 'Median'..

1. Create a Bezier Curve
2. Edit Mode, Right-Click menu, subdivide it once.
3. Select the 3 vertices, hit <kbd>V</kbd>. set their type to 'Vector'
4. Select the left 2 vertices, and <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> straighten them parallel to Y
5. Drag the other vertex roughly where you want the tip of the arch. Doesn't really matter yet.
6. In the curve's 'Data' tab > 'Shape' panel, set its type to 2D. In the 'Geometry' panel, give the curve an extrusion to the depth of your arch:

[image]

(The blue version is just a rotated copy to show you the extrusion.)

You're almost done.

7. (left) Give the curve a *Solidify* modifier, set to 'Complex' and 'Even'
8. (middle) Give the curve a *Mirror* modifier, across X, with 'Bisect' and possibly 'Flip'  in X, too. You'll see..

[image]

You can now adjust the shape, depth, and thickness of your arch as much as you like, without reworking joints, etc. At any point, you can convert the curve to a mesh.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - it's the only method of the ones given so far that ensures a consistent thickness between the "side" and "roof" segments.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Although the original image in the question doesn't look like it has a consistent thickness. So whilst this is a great answer, it doesn't necessarily make it more "acceptable".

Comment: @MrWhite Hmm, fair enough - I was looking at the OP's first attempt, and that was at least trying to use equal thickness...

Comment: my only additional question is, why are there 5 answers to such a simple question

Comment: @MikoCG the only reason I chucked one in was because the uneven thickness was making me all twitchy :) But for all I know, it doesn't make the OP twitchy at all :)

Answer (score 5):

**STEP 1**

[image]

**STEP 2**

[image]

***extrude and apply the mirror modifier as shown in the second video***

Answer (score 4):

You should build that from 1 single mesh like this
Create 1 cube:
[image]

go to edit mode, take all vertices to the one side, scale it down a little to your needs like this:
[image]

use mirror modifier with axis value (in my case it is Y axis) and enable clipping:
[image]

move the top face upward, extend another face and shape it to your needs:
[image]
now for that last part, you can either use your eyes and try to make it look right or... pres G and G again to slide your edge, press alt while moving and you will be able to move toward the middle like this:
[image]
(sorry I cant take picture while holding alt...), but you just slide it to the top and clipping will connect it... remove the extra face at the top and merge vertices

Comment: Can't take a picture while holding _Alt_? I press _Alt_ with my left index finger and take a screenshot with my right index finger...  :D

Comment: I use windows key+shift+S for selected screenshot and it doesn't work while holding alt it seems :D

Comment: Oh, I see.... didn't think of that.

Comment: @MikoCG Open Snip & Sketch and the dropdown arrow in the top left lets you take a screenshot after 3 or 10 seconds.  I use it a lot to take screenshots mid-operation or several clicks deep in a menu.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see, there are many ways to construct this object. Here is another way.

1. Add a *Cube* object to your scene. Go into front view for example by hitting <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> and rotate it by 45°: Press <kbd>R</kbd> > <kbd>4</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> > <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Or in any other view after hitting <kbd>R</kbd>, press <kbd>Y</kbd> first to constrain the rotation to the X axis. Now select the two bottom faces.

[image: 45 degree cube]

2. Next press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Individual Faces*, drag them as far out as needed and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>LMB</kbd> to confirm the extrusion.

[image: extrude]

[image: finished extrude]

3. Now use the *Knife Tool* by pressing <kbd>K</kbd> to cut the extruded regions. Press <kbd>C</kbd> for angle constraint to get a straight horizontal cut and <kbd>Z</kbd> to enable cut through the backside as well. You can see in the status bar if the options are enabled. You can start by snapping the knife to the left or right corner vertex, if it is snapped to it the square green symbol gets a red border line. Then move to the the other corner, left-click to place the cut, then <kbd>Return</kbd> to confirm cutting.

[image: knife tool]

4. After cutting, select the bottom edges and press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete* > *Vertices*. Select the now open edges and close them by filling in faces with <kbd>F</kbd>. The new faces should be selected after being created.

[image: delete bottom]

5. With the new bottom faces selected, hit <kbd>E</kbd> to simply extrude them downwards as far as it is necessary. And you're done.

[image: complete]

Answer (score 1):

Draw your shape, put it up as a background image.

Take a square turn it 90⁰, edge on camera. Turn on mirror modifier.

Extrude from face of square along shape of triangle. Mirror modifier should fill in other half for you.

There's 10s of ways to do it though. Even your model there, the first one...delete the faces of the ends where it overlaps. Join them together with a merge edge loop or just merge vertices. Drag that joint to the shape you want, throwing in edge loops where you can't get the shape exact.